# How to take out the quotation marks(start & end) and convert into bytes - Python 3.7.9

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm receiving from an input this,

```
"b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMBgCEQCZ0e8OKi/eLXMXxPrhdFc3AgMBAAE=\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'"
```

and i'm struggling to make it become a bytes, and not string, and be able to load the keys without problems - ValueError: No PEM start marker "b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'" found.

Changing to bytes using the `b''`, tried replacing it, tried using the `strip()`. etc

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.9+ : You have `.removesuffix()` and `.removeprefix()` options.

In lower versions, You can simply slice the string from character two, until before the last one.

Then you can use `.encode()` to convert your string to byte:

```py
old_string = "b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMBgCEQCZ0e8OKi/eLXMXxPrhdFc3AgMBAAE=\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'"
new_string1 = old_string.removeprefix("b'").removesuffix("'").encode("ASCII")
new_string2 = old_string[2:-1].encode("ASCII")

print(type(old_string), old_string)
print(type(new_string1), new_string1)
print(type(new_string2), new_string2)
```

output:

```
<class 'str'> b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMBgCEQCZ0e8OKi/eLXMXxPrhdFc3AgMBAAE=\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
<class 'bytes'> b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMBgCEQCZ0e8OKi/eLXMXxPrhdFc3AgMBAAE=\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'
<class 'bytes'> b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMBgCEQCZ0e8OKi/eLXMXxPrhdFc3AgMBAAE=\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'
```

By default `.encode()` uses `"UTF-8"` but since your dealing with ASCII characters it won't cause problem. You can pass `"ASCII"` if you want.

Comment: at the moment I can't use python 3.9, are there any workarounds to remove the prefix and suffix?

Comment: @ȶɦɛֆɦɨռʏɛռɖ "Slicing" as I mentioned. Look at `new_string2`.

Comment: Yeah, tried that also.. no success

Comment: @ȶɦɛֆɦɨռʏɛռɖ What was the problem? Did you get an exception?

Comment: Yes there was an error, but, it has been a day, and I managed to figure a solution, Thank you very much for your time and help, much appreciated